# How to fix error with GitLab runner inside Kubernetes cluster - try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup two VMs that I am using throughout my journey of educating myself in CI/CD, GitLab, Kubernetes, Cloud Computing in general and so on. Both VMs have Ubuntu 22.04 Server as a host.

**VM1 - MicroK8s Kubernetes cluster**

Most of the setup is "default". Since I'm not really that knowledgeable, I have only configured two pods and their respective services - one with PostGIS and the other one with GeoServer. My intent is to add a third pod, which is the deployment of a app that I a have in VM2 and that will communicate with the GeoServer in order to provide a simple map web service (Leaflet + Django). All pods are exposed both within the cluster via internal IPs as well as externally (`externalIp`).

I have also installed two GitLab-related components here:

- **GitLab Runner** with **Kubernetes as executor**
- **GitLab Kubernetes Agent**

In VM2 both are visible as connected.

**VM2 - GitLab**

Here is where GitLab (default installation, latest version) runs. In the configuration (`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`) I have enabled the **agent server**.

Initially I had the runner in VM1 configured to have Docker as executor. I had not issues with that. However then I thought it would be nice to try out running the runner inside the cluster so that everything is capsuled (using the internal cluster IPs without further configuration and exposing the VM's operating system).

Both the runner and agent are showing as connected but running a pseudo-CI/CD pipeline (the one provided by GitLab, where you have **build**, **test** and **deploy** stages with each consisting of a simple `echo` and waiting for a few seconds) returns the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.2 (4d1ca121)
  on testcluster-k8s-runner Hko2pDKZ, system ID: s_072d6d140cfe
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
```

I am unable to find any information regarding `KUBERNETES_MASTER` except in issue tickets (GitLab) and questions (SO and other Q&A platforms). I have no idea what it is, where to set it. My guess would be it belongs in the runner's configuration on VM1 or at least the environment of the `gitlab-runner` (the user that contains the runner's userspace with its respective `/home/gitlab-runner` directory).

The only one possible solution I have found so far is to create the `.kube` directory from the user which uses `kubectl` (in my case `microk8s kubectl` since I use MicroK8s) to the home directory of the GitLab runner. I didn't see anything special in this directory (no hidden files) except for a `cache` subdirectory, hence my decision to simply create it at `/home/gitlab-runner/.kube`, which didn't change a thing.

Comment: I have the same thing, and I think I had it working at one point, but it's broken now. There is very little about this, especially from Gitlab.